# Are these the null-terminator rules for MultiByteToWideChar() and WideCharToMultiByte()? I don't quite understand MSDN

Tags: winapi, encoding

I'm trying to make sure my code for converting between UTF-8 and UTF-16 is correct with regards to the null terminator.

In the case of `MultiByteToWideChar()`, I understand that if you pass an output buffer size of 0, you get the number of characters **including** the terminating null. My question is: do you pass the count **including** the terminating null as your new buffer size, and compare against the count **including** the terminating null? Or in other words, is this correct?

```
n = MultiByteToWideChar(..., NULL, 0);
if (MultiByteToWideChar(..., buf, n) != n) error();
```

I'm guessing from the blurb under the input buffer size

> If this parameter is set to a positive integer, the function processes exactly the specified number of bytes. If the provided size does not include a terminating null character, the resulting Unicode string is not null-terminated, and the returned length does not include this character.

and an input buffer size of -1 that the answer is yes; is that so?

For `WideCharToMultiByte()`, I'm not sure about null terminators at all. If I pass 0 for the output buffer count, will the returned count include null terminators or not? For the actual conversion, do I say the output buffer's size includes the null terminator or not? And does the return value include the null terminator or not?

My current code answers these with no, no, and no (respectively). This seems to work, but I'd rather not trust code that works by accident. My only hint is the following blurb:

> If this parameter is -1, the function processes the entire input string, including the terminating null character. Therefore, the resulting character string has a terminating null character, and the length returned by the function includes this character.

so I'm thinking the answers are really yes, yes, and yes, but I'm still not entirely sure.

Thanks.

For good measure, here's my code:

```
// note: assume logLastError() calls DebugBreak() and that uiAlloc() aborts on failure

#define MBTWC(str, wstr, bufsiz) MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str, -1, wstr, bufsiz)

WCHAR *toUTF16(const char *str)
{
    WCHAR *wstr;
    int n;

    n = MBTWC(str, NULL, 0);
    if (n == 0)
        logLastError("error figuring out number of characters to convert to in toUTF16()");
    wstr = (WCHAR *) uiAlloc(n * sizeof (WCHAR), "WCHAR[]");
    // TODO verify return includes null terminator
    if (MBTWC(str, wstr, n) != n)
        logLastError("error converting from UTF-8 to UTF-16 in toUTF16()");
    return wstr;
}

#define WCTMB(wstr, str, bufsiz) WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr, -1, str, bufsiz, NULL, FALSE)

char *toUTF8(const WCHAR *wstr)
{
    char *str;
    int n;

    n = WCTMB(wstr, NULL, 0);
    if (n == 0)
        logLastError("error figuring out number of characters to convert to in toUTF8()");
    // TODO does n include the null terminator?
    str = (char *) uiAlloc((n + 1) * sizeof (char), "char[]");
    if (WCTMB(wstr, str, n + 1) != n)
        logLastError("error converting from UTF-16 to UTF-8 in toUTFF8()");
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the return value of [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072.aspx) says:

> If the function succeeds and cchWideChar is 0, the return value is the required size, in characters, for the buffer indicated by lpWideCharStr.

So, to your questions.

> If I pass 0 for the output buffer count, will the returned count include null terminators or not?

Yes, if you passed `-1` to `cbMultiByte`. No if you passed `strlen(lpMultiByteStr)`.

> For the actual conversion, do I say the output buffer's size includes the null terminator or not?

Yes if you want the buffer to be null-terminated, no if you do not.

---

So, having done:

```
n = MultiByteToWideChar(..., -1, NULL, 0);
```

You can choose to allocate a buffer of length `n` if you want the buffer null-terminated, or allocate a buffer of length `n-1` if you do not want it null-terminated. Obviously you need to pass either `n` or `n-1` as the `cchWideChar` parameter, to match the actual length of your buffer.

---

Looking at your code, it's clear that you want to create null-terminated buffers. Your code for `toUTF16` is correct. Your code for `toUTF8` is not. You should use the same length handling code as you did in `toUTF16`. What's more, your final parameter to `WideCharToMultiByte` is a little imprecise. It's a pointer to a boolean. The code should be:

```
#define WCTMB(wstr, str, bufsiz) WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr, -1, str, bufsiz, NULL, NULL)

char *toUTF8(const WCHAR *wstr)
{
    char *str;
    int n;

    n = WCTMB(wstr, NULL, 0);
    if (n == 0)
        logLastError("error figuring out number of characters to convert to in toUTF8()");
    str = (char *) uiAlloc(n * sizeof (char), "char[]");
    if (WCTMB(wstr, str, n) != n)
        logLastError("error converting from UTF-16 to UTF-8 in toUTFF8()");
    return str;
}
```

Comment: So the return should be equal to the output size and `WideCharToMultiByte()` follows the same rules then. Thanks! Also thanks for spotting the last parameter issue; I compile with `-Wall -Wextra` and I'm surprised gcc didn't catch that...